# Can a parent choose which child to instantiate?

Tags: ruby, oop

If I have a class Animal, and Animal is passed animal_type which is the type of animal.  Can Animal use that information to instantiate a child from itself?  Wouldn't this be a good thing if the class instantiating the object doesn't care about the type of object it is creating?  And it removes the case statements required to decide which subclass to instantiate.

For example:

```
@animal = Animal.new(cat) which instantiates a Cat < Animal object.
```

Comment: This strikes me as rather perverse in a language like Ruby. If `animal_type` is actually a type of animal, you should just instantiate `animal_type` — just do `animal_type.new` instead of `Animal.new(animal_type)`. No case statement or fancy yak-shaving required. Message dispatch already does the work of figuring out the class of the receiver and calling the appropriate method for you.

Comment: @Chuck: if `animal_type` comes from yaml, it's much easier to have `:cat` in a yaml file than the yaml for the `Cat` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Please look up **Factory** design pattern.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that you could override self.new in rails :) cool.

Comment: It's not about overriding self.new really.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is, but if you want to create an instance of a class from a variable, you can just call the `Class#new` method:

```
@animal = cat.new
```

If you only want this to happen if the class instance `cat` is a subclass of `Animal`, then do

```
@animal = cat.new if cat.superclass == Animal
```